# Mathf.Clamp having strange behaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clamp

So i have a simple character controller but i want to clamp the camera so that i cant turn 180 degree vertically. As far as i know my code should have worked.

The values i want it to clamp by are min-70 and max70. But whenever i enter those as Min and Max nothing changes.
This is my current code

```cs
            float x = Mathf.Clamp(_joystick.Vertical * (_moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime), camMin, camMax);
            myCamera.transform.eulerAngles -= new Vector3(x, 0);
```

I feel like im missing something by now but i am unable to find what. So any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: The first thing to do is verify the values are what you think they are. Either step to that point with a debugger or do ```Console.Writeline($"{_joystick.Vertical * (_moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime)} -- camMin -- camMax");``` and check the values are as expected

Comment: @John Unity specific you rather want `Debug.Log($"{_joystick.Vertical * (_moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime)} -- {camMin} -- {camMax}");`

Answer (score 0):

You are only clamping the *change* in angle, not the actual angle. You should do something like:

```
var angles = myCamera.transform.eulerAngles;
var x = angles.X + _joystick.Vertical * (_moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
x = Mathf.Clamp(x, camMin, camMax);
myCamera.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(x, angles.Y, angles.Z);
```

Comment: Hey, This atleast fixed it for 50%. Currently it clamps it perfectly when looking down. But whenever i try to look up, at the moment the x gets to 0, it resets back to 70 instead of going to into the - towards -70

Comment: @Bloemenpot I would try removing the clamp, or double check that the clamp values are correct, since values close to zero should not be affected by the clamp at all. I would recommend checking the values in the debugger to see that they match your expectations. I dislike dealing with euler angles, since there are 12 possible variants, and it is not at all intuitive what each angle actually mean, so that is one possible source for errors.

Comment: Careful: you do not want to do this via [eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) directly I would always actually use `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x, 0, 0);` if there is another place handling the `y` then also explicitly store the `y` and apply it through the `Quaternion.Euler` as well